# selenium code to fetch data from excel

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am using below mentioned selenium code to fetch data from excel and type that in textbox of website. It is fetching and storing data correctly in object array but it is giving me error while writing that data in excel i.e last line of the code is not working. Can anyone help me that how can i pass value of obj[0][2] into textbox ?

```
XLSDatatable_Connectivity data= new XLSDatatable_Connectivity (System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\Excel\\CreateUser.xlsx");    
int rows= data.totalRow("CreateUser");
int column= data.totalColumn("CreateUser");


Object obj[][]=new Object[rows-1][column];

for(int row=2; row<=rows;row++)
{
    for(int col=0;col<column;col++)
    {
    obj[row-2][col]= data.getData("CreateUser", col, row);
    }
}

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='oUsersInfo_Name']")).sendKeys(obj[0][2]);
```

Comment: Holy crap. Selenium can pull data from Excel. I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: What is the error it's giving you?

Comment: @GlenPierce XLSDatatable_Connectivity is not a Selenium Class. He probably made the class himself or uses a library.

Comment: @swati It looks like bad design you're getting "Object" classes out of the excel sheet. There's no way to know what type of stuff you're trying to put into the textfield for us now. Could you clear up where the XLSDatatable_Connectivity class comes from?

Comment: @GlenPierce Selenium isn't pulling data from Excel. That's Java and some other library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: if i pass driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='oUsersInfo_Name']")).sendKeys("swati"); it works fine completely... but if i want to pass value stored in my object how can i do that ?

Comment: XLSDatatable_Connectivity is from library... there is no issue with this part

Answer (score 1):

You should use @Dataprovider to pass your test data into test class. Please follow this
[Link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-data-provider-excel/)